# Помощь с Reduce

Tags: javascript

Друзья, Всем доброго времени суток. Помогите решить вопрос именно через reduce, уже голову ломаю, не могу въехать как он работает. У меня есть некий массив и в нем объект и нужно через reduce совершить поиск по свойству 'name'
Я что-то пытался, но у меня метод возвращает только последний элемент, хотя в консоль выводит точно как надо.

На выходе функция должна вернуть:

{ name: "third", value: 5}

```js
const testArr = [
  { name: "first", value: 1 },
  { name: "second", value: 2 },
  { name: "third", value: 5 },
  { name: "fourth", value: 1 },
  { name: "fifth", value: 2 }
];

const searchItem = string => {
  return testArr.reduce((acc, curret) => {
    if (curret.name === string) {
      return curret
    }
  }, {})
}

console.log(searchItem('second')); // undefined
```

и если не у кого-то есть идеи как можно создать еще такой объект так же reduce

```js
{
  "1":  { name: ['first', 'fourth']} },
  "2":  { name: ['second', 'fifth']} },
  "5" : { name: ['third'] }
}
```

буду очень признателен!
Спасибо за помощь и ваше время!

Comment: Чтобы хорошо прочувствовать, надо выполнить задачу через обычный цикл, потом "перевести" его на reduce) P.s. для этой задачи были бы уместнее `.find()` или `.filter()`

Comment: `if (curret.name === string) {return curret} else {return acc}`.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает, осталось понять как этот метод вообще функционирует